# Why one need to implement web-hooks if pusher are working well?

Tags: webhooks, pusher

Why one need to implement webhooks if pusher are working well?

Are `web-hooks` and pusher are interchangeable or `web-hooks` better than `pusher`

Answer (score 2):

> Are web-hooks and pusher are interchangeable

No, they are different technologies and have different use cases

> or web-hooks better than pusher

They are not interchangeable and cannot be compared in this fashion.

[Web Hooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) are a standardised way for a service to send a message to another service/api using regular HTTPS calls and have to be registered on the sender's side.

Looking at [Pusher](https://pusher.com/features), though seems to be an service providing the ability to provide [push notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) to web browsers and apps.

**UPDATE** Just noticed that Pusher does appear to offer web hook integration as well for Pusher related events.